# Add support command line

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I developed a GUI application for macOS to record video from a computer screen. Can I add support command line? Example,

```
$myapp -start // Start recording video
$myapp -stop // Stop recording video
```

and etc.

If it's possible, then how can I implemented it?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you wish to produce a command line version of your app, control a GUI version of your app using the command line, or something else? Answers people provide will probably depend on this. (You can edit the question to clarify.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably make more sense to create a dedicated command-line tool, built by its own target, and include that as a "helper" executable in your application bundle.

You can then have your application install that as a command-line tool in `/usr/local/bin/` by copying it, creating a hard link, etc. If it's a completed tool consider also installing a man page for it.